# Manipulating the corners of an SVG with a image uri inside of it

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to write a script in JS where I can drag the corners of an SVG with an image URI inside around the screen and have it warp I can't use anything like node or three.js because this is a project I am making a scratch extension for my class to use.

I want to go from this
[image: Original Square Image]

to this
[image: New warped SVG]

Comment: SVG does not support non-affine transforms. 3D css may work on some browsers though.